# JS - Assign hidden value to cell

Tags: javascript, cell, tablecell

Is there a way to assign a hidden value to a table cell? I would like to assign a certain value, an integer or a string to a table cell, so I can append and edit this value in javascript by using the id.

Comment: Why don't you just set an attribute? You can use JSON if you want to keep the type of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try HTML5's data api. You can set an attribute on the cell:

```
<td id="cell1" data-value="1">One</td><td id="cell2" data-value="2">Two</td>
```

You can then use:

```
document.getElementById('cell1').dataset.value;
```

Comment: Neat, didn't know about this! Will definitely come in handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an attribute named 'data-' fowlloed by anything to any DOM node. Use the standard attribute access and change functions to read and write the value which will of course be a string.